# IBM BlueMix: LifeRay 7 Installation

Tags: liferay, ibm-cloud

I get the following error while deploying LifeRay 7. I am not sure where ServiceDependencyListener is included (can't find it in the sources). Is it a shared TomCat library?

```
STG/211-----> Uploading droplet (197M)2016-07-21T00:59:36.393+0200
DEA/211Starting app instance (index 0) with guid c2ec8b5e-1b11-42f0-82e8-b58960598be62016-07-21T00:59:48.797+0200
App/0[CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol INFO Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-61399"]2016-07-21T00:59:56.875+0200
App/0[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina INFO Initialization processed in 687 ms2016-07-21T00:59:56.883+0200
App/0[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService INFO Starting service Catalina2016-07-21T00:59:56.893+0200
App/0[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine INFO Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.362016-07-21T00:59:56.893+0200
App/0[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig INFO Deploying web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT2016-07-21T00:59:56.921+0200
App/0[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase SEVERE ContainerBase.addChild: start:2016-07-21T01:00:09.651+0200
App/0org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]2016-07-21T01:00:09.651+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)2016-07-21T01:00:09.651+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)2016-07-21T01:00:09.651+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)2016-07-21T01:00:09.651+0200
App/0at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/registry/dependency/ServiceDependencyListener2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:86)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:335)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5202)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:306)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.registry.dependency.ServiceDependencyListener2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0... 10 more2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0... 24 more2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig SEVERE Error deploying web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)2016-07-21T01:00:09.652+0200
App/0[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig INFO Deployment of web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 12,733 ms2016-07-21T01:00:09.660+0200
App/0[CONTAINER] pplicationStartupFailureDetectingLifecycleListener SEVERE Error: Application '' failed (state = FAILED): see Tomcat's logs for details. Halting Tomcat.2016-07-21T01:00:09.664+0200
App/02016-07-21T01:00:09.720+0200
DEA/211Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections2016-07-21T01:00:09.786+0200
API/1App instance exited with guid c2ec8b5e-1b11-42f0-82e8-b58960598be6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"c2ec8b5e-1b11-42f0-82e8-b58960598be6", "version"=>"28e1bf62-2b97-40e0-a46b-355b81d6c94f", "instance"=>"478bc5a6d52548a688e166bca89a0bf4", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>148, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1469055609}2016-07-21T01:00:09.804+0200
```

So far I placed all LifeRay dependencies within:
    /WEB-INF/lib/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check if the liferay dependencies are resolved?

It seems that you missed up a jar file...

Check [here](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/installing-liferay-on-tomcat-8) liferay 7.0 dependencies that must be resolved...

If you need any of those jars then you have to copy it to your application server

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the missing OSGI container. LifeRay places this outside the TomCat folder. I reconfigured the *.war and deployed it afterwards. Now this is working / resolved.

Thanks!